# Identifying threads in game (TCP related also)

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, game-development

This is a school project, please do not provide any code, I am only looking for hints to guide me in the right direction.

Write and test a game server that clients subscribe to. Once subscribed, the client receives 
a list of games (the same game, just different 'instances' of it) currently in play. The client may then elect to join a game or start a new 
one.  A game must have at least two players before actually starting. The system must support multiple clients all playing one game, or multiple clients playing multiple games.

The objective of this project is to gain experience in Java, TCP, and threading.

My current design and implementation has 2 files: server.java and client.java

1. The server file has 3 classes: Server, Lobby and Game
2. The client file has 1 class: Client.

The implementation of the "game" is trivial, I am fine with that.

Currently, the server class establishes the TCP connection with the client class.
Each time a client is instantiated, the socket is accepted in the server class, and the program continues.

Continuing on, the server class creates the lobby class.

The lobby class is where I am having **trouble** with. By default, I am creating 1 "game" object, and passing in the clientSocket:

```
game g = new game(clientSocket, playerID);                 
g.start();
```

The game class extends thread, which I think is the correct way of doing it. Each "game" will be a separate thread, so to speak, so players A and B can share 1 thread, and players C and D can start a new game with another thread.

I am new to threads, but this is the best implementation I could think of. I ruled out having multiple threads for lobby's, since that doesn't really make sense, and multiple threads for clients is pointless too, so I think multi-threading the games class is ideal.

Right now, when I create 2 instances of the client, they are both joining the same 'thread' (they are both in the same game and can talk to each other).

How am I supposed to do it so that, a new player can type "new" or whatever in the lobby and create a new "game", where it's a new thread.

I'm sure I mis-understood certain parts about threading or whatnot, but I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html
If not, it may be a good place to start.

Comment: Yes, I have taken a look at it. Thank you though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would suggest you read on multiplayer game development and networking in Java (UDP/TCP). I am no game-developer but simply happenned to take a Java networking course in college and had a similar project (a networked game).

Secondly, dealing with multiple threads is proportional to complexity. You want to minimize complexity. I would suggest to abandon an "*I have to find a place to use threads*" mentality. (Don't force a square peg in a round hole ;))

Continuing, following through the requirements:

**Write and test a game server that clients subscribe to.**

> IIRC, this is fairly straightforward (and you're probably past this part).

**Once subscribed, the client receives a list of games (the same game, just different 'instances' of it) currently in play**

> This should be fairly straightforward as well since a TCP connection between the server and client have been established already.
>
> However, there are a couple of things to understand at this point. The most important, perhaps, is that there will be a single central server that will hold information on all connected clients and existing games. This consequently means that it has to be the one to deal with the state of the system (e.g. tracking currently existing gamerooms), client requests (to create/join gamerooms), as well as updating clients with relevant info on the system's state (e.g. created/closed gamerooms).
>
> Another consideration at this point is the scope of client's functionality in the system. A typical implementation would probably be a *fat-server, thin-client* architecture. Basically, this means that a client does no real processing of data (from user input) and instead relies on the server. Most of the time, then, the client is only waiting for input from user or a response from the server. On the otherhand, the server deals with the processing of data from clients, updating the system state (including individual game states), and notifying concerned client of relevant changes in the system/game state.

**The client may then elect to join a game or start a new one**

> What actually happens here is a client sending data "I elect to join a game" or "I elect to create a game" to the server. The server acts on this and notifies concerned clients (I say *concerned* and not *all* since some clients could possibly be playing and do not need to know whether new games have spawned).

**A game must have at least two players before actually starting.**

> -

**The system must support multiple clients all playing one game, or multiple clients playing multiple games.**

> Again depending on the client-server architecture, either the server will be doing all the processing (*fat-server, thin-client*) or the clients (*thin-server, fat-client*) do the processing while the server mainly serves as a relay point to other clients. I have no definite (or even confident) suggestion on this, however, as I am simply overwhelmed by the sheer number of possible implementations and their consequences. Thus, I can't really encourage enough to read more on networking and game development. Individually, those 2 topics are incredibly vast, much more when combined.

Lastly, with regards to the use of threads. IIRC, dispatching separate threads for opened sockets are useful in preventing the application from getting blocked waiting  for input. I don't really agree with your idea of "hosting" a game in a thread but since you're in school I can only admire your trying things out.

This may help you further: [Lesson: All About Sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html). And you might perhaps also be interested in [UDP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/MulticastSocket.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed post. I'll work some more on the project later today and post back. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't map games to threads. Instead, map clients to threads. Each client will have their own thread that does work initiated by the receipt of commands from that client. When you need to create a new game, just create a new object in a shared collection of games. Track, in the client instance, which game, if any, it's associated with.

If you find you really do need a thread to manage a game, then you can create one. When a client sends a command to a particular game, just put that command on a queue of commands that's read by the thread managing that game. The game thread only needs to know which game it's managing. It can terminate itself when that game is finished.

Comment: I really don't get this answer. At first you say don't map games to threads, but then you say the game thread only needs to know which game it is managing, implying that you HAVE mapped games to threads...

Comment: @MirroredFate I say that in the second paragraph, which begins with "**if** you find you really do **need** a thread to manage a game". For example, you might need something to happen in a game if nobody does something for a certain amount of time. That might be best managed with a thread. But reacting to something a player did is usually best done in the thread that realized the player did that thing.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll get back to you soon!